# How can I log the output of the mv command in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I'm using the command:

```
mv -v -f sourceDir destDir
```

How can I output the verbose console out to a file?

Comment: Please make clear if the use case is 'shell scripting' or 'interactive shell usage'. 
For shell scripting the answer gt6989b applies. For interactive shell usage my answer applies.

Comment: I used it for interactive mode, i wanted to move a large set of files from one disk that was falling to another which is new, and search after for failed copy attemps in order to know which files where not copied. in windows i know "xcopy source dest >>C:\files.txt " could do the job but windows could not read the file system correctly (NTFS !) and Linux Mint did ! Thanks for your answers will try them soon

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `mv -v -f sourceDir destDir > out.file 2> err.file`

Comment: Just tried this. It works.

Answer (score 9):

Invoke:

```
 exec > >(tee /tmp/logfile)
```

All the output (to stdout) of your next commands will be duplicated to the logfile.
This will continue till you leave the shell.

If you want this only for some commands create a subshell with:

```
bash | tee /tmp/logfile
```

Comment: And how would he revert that?

Comment: Should be clear now :-)

Comment: That's nice for logging the output of many commands. Upvoted! =)